# Excel - Find first value in a range that is =< 0 and return the date

Tags: excel, range, formula

So im making an excel spreadsheet and I have a scenario in which I am trying to forecast out some values and I need to use a combination of formulas that will help me find the first value that is less than or equal to 0 from the range of values in the row and return the date above. I have included a screen shot of what i am talking about. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: 'Match' and 'Index'

Comment: Is the data always descending order because I can post a second  answer if it isn't.

Comment: It will fluctuate up and down but it is trending towards 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data in row 3 is sorted descending, so Match() can be used with -1 as the third parameter. With that, though, Match returns the smallest value that is greater than or equal to the lookup value, so, if there is no 0 in the range, the next cell to the LEFT is returned, which is not what you want.

Therefore, the formula must first find the matching value, then test if it is 0 or less, and if not adjust the returned Match value by 1.

This leads to

```
=IF(INDEX(B3:G3,MATCH(0,B3:G3,-1))<=0,INDEX(B1:G1,MATCH(0,B3:G3,-1)),INDEX(B1:G1,MATCH(0,B3:G3,-1)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: And this will work with data that will flucuate up and down but is trending towards 0?

Comment: It will work as long as the numbers are in descending order.